# How to configure AWS Device Farm for testing Android native apps like Calculator?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, testing, appium, aws-device-farm

I am new to Appium and I am trying to run manual and automated tests on the AWS Device Farm. While I am trying to 'Create a new run', it wants me to upload an apk file.

[Create a new run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oc9yP.png)

But, when upload the apk and run the test, it gives me the below error during the 'Setup Suite' phase.

Error: 
Package com.google.android.calculator is already installed as a default system app

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hu9XN.png)

Please let me know if you need additional info that I may have missed to resolve the issue. Many thanks in anticipation!

Answer (score 1):

You are seeing this error because you're uploading a system app that is already installed on the device.

There is a work around where you could upload a dummy apk and in your Appium tests specifically target the calculator app.